# How to convert text file into dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have only worked with key, value pairs where
`{a:"b", d:"c"}` there are only 2 values. If I have a file that has something like this

```
{
  "personalInformationDeltaEmployee": {
    "employeeID": "0",
    "actualSSN": null
  },
  "appointmentDeltaEmployee": {
    "cyberSecurityCode3": "0",
    "POID": "0"
  }
}
```

This file we are assuming is a txt file. How would I convert something like this into a dictionary?

This is what I tried:

```
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        line_dict = {}
        for part in filename:
            key, value = part.split(":")
            line_dict[key] = value
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

I get need more than 1 value to unpack. I'm guessing it's mad about the extra bracket, right? What would be the best way to go about this and what are some options I can look into?

Comment: You can't parse something unless it follows some format. The data you show is JSON, so `json.load(open("filename"))` is all you need.  In your code, `for part in filename:` certainly isn't what you want - part would just be the letters of the filename. Generally, its good to know the format of the thing you are trying to parse and to use existing parsers if you can.

Comment: If I use json.load I end up with string with "u" characters and the order looks different from the original file. Is the best solution here to use a for loop to get rid of anything that fits (u')

Comment: You you need to use 2.x? It been depricated for a long time. Those are `unicode` characters (in python 3, `str` is unicode and `unicode` has been depricated) and work much the same is regular strings.

Comment: Unfortunately yes it has to be in Python 2.7, but thanks for clarifying

Comment: A `unicode` string like `u"employeeID"` doesn't really have a "u" on front. Its python's way of telling you its unicode. It may work perfectly fine in your application. If not, you could parse with json then go through the result and convert everything to `str` by decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is in JSON format, you can use the `json` module to parse it into a Python dictionary. In Python 2 strings aren't Unicode, so you'll also need to convert all Unicode strings in the input into that format.

Here's how to do that using a helper function. Note that the order of items in the result may not be the same as the input because in Python 2, dictionaries don't preserve the order-of-insertion.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    raise RuntimeError('Requires Python 2')

def unicode_convert(obj):
    """ Convert unicode data to string in object and return it. """

    if isinstance(obj, unicode):
        obj = obj.encode()
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        obj = map(unicode_convert, obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):  # Converts contents in-place.
        for key, value in obj.items():  # Copy of dict's (key, value) pairs (Py2)
            del obj[key]
            if isinstance(key, unicode):
                key = key.encode()
            if isinstance(value, (unicode, list, dict)):
                value = unicode_convert(value)
            obj[key] = value

    return obj


with open('personal_info.json') as file:
    info = json.load(file)  # Parse JSON object into Python dictionary.
    line_dict = {key: value for key, value in unicode_convert(info).items()}

pprint(line_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a lot of headache. May I ask what "codecs" is used for?

Comment: Oops, sorry, just a leftover from something I was trying.